# Specify border-color for entire document in css

Tags: css, stylesheet

Isn't it possible to set the border-color once in the stylesheet to use as standard for all elements? 
-I've tried `* {border-color: #FF8A8A;}` in stylesheet.css and then put for example `h2 {font-size:150%; border-bottom: solid 1px; }`, but the border shows up black.

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to set the border-color like this? Or am I misunderstaning the use of * ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [W3School about border properties](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp):

> If the border color is not set it is inherited from the color property
>   of the element.
>
> **Note:** The "border-color" property does not work if it is used alone.
>   Use the "border-style" property to set the borders first.

So you the code would be something like this:

> ```
> * {
>     border-style: solid;
>     border-color: red;
> }
>
> div {
>     border-width: 1px;
>   }
> ```

But I do not suggest this method because you are applying a border color to ALL elements on the page including BODY, HTML, all DIVs etc.

Comment: So it's not possible to set the border-color globally at all without adding borders to every element on the page? (except maybe by adding border-style:none; to all elements, but that would defeat the purpose of using globally set colors to simplify coding)

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Usually I set border color as needed per element. If you have a lot of elements that need borders to be a certain color I would just have a CSS class called .borders and then in your CSS just apply this class to any element that needed it. <div class="whatever border">blah</div>

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to manually then set each property separately, like:

```
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
```

This way the color will take your global color property.

Comment: Nope, I've tried this, but it didn't make any difference